# Toggle List with Button

Tags: buttons, lists, toggle

Let me explain what i need.

In a "add new person" form, the user has the option to select the kinds of person that this new person applies... Like, this company is a customer, and is also a relocation partner and a redispatch carrier.

And each one of these options has their specific data... The customer has credit card info, the relocation partner has the stretches that he horks on, so each one opens it's on modal when the user clicks on the button.

Something like that:

[image: Example]

In this case, the first and third options are enabled, so this person is a "Cliente" and a "Agente". So the user toggles that checkbox, and clicks on the "Cliente" button to add the specific info...

I don't know if that is the best way to display something like that to the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save clicks and effort by simply removing the radio buttons.

Why don't you simply let the user click on the buttons on the right (e.g. "Cliente") to open a modal? Once that is filled out you can display a little checkmark image right of the button.

To indicate the opening of a modal on button click you should consider changing the text to "Cliente..." or "Enter customer information..."

This way you save one click, but also fix the problematic appearance of the radio buttons and buttons:

- They are displayed as radio buttons while functioning like check boxes (radio buttons are used for multiple choice - single answer while check boxes are for multiple choice - multiple answers).
- The buttons appear to stay inactive even when selecting a radio button
- The list itself isn't recognizable for most users probably. I'm not even sure if I'd manage to "use it correctly" considering the issues I mentioned above.

Good luck!